# Объединить три массива в один, отсортировав его значения в порядке возрастания

Tags: javascript, массивы, веб-программирование

```
Используя JavaScript на веб-странице объединить три массива
в один массив
```

Comment: `console.log([...A, ...B, ...C].sort())`

Comment: @entithat `.sort((a,b) => a - b)` пустой sort() по умолчанию сортирует элементы как строки)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, но цифры  в числах то будут от 0 до 9, не знаю что там может пойти не так, что нельзя просто без компаратора писать

Comment: `<button onclick="concatArray()">Concat</button>`, где `concatArray()` функция в js

Comment: @entithat `[1, 10, 100, 2, 20, 200, 4, 40, 400]` — При сравнении строк "2" больше чем "100": Первый символ оказался больше, сравнивание останавливается)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, действительно, а я что-то вцепился в тест 20, 29, думая при этом какие же тут могут камни подводные быть. Да, согласен :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
const div = document.querySelector('#div')

const a = [20, 10, 40]
const b = [2, 1, 4]
const c = [200, 100, 400]

const d = [...a,...b,...c]
d.sort((a, b) => a - b)

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  div.textContent = d
})
```

```html
<div id='div'></div>
<button id='btn'>вывести</button>
```